# Get tumblr note count without an API key

Tags: share, tumblr

Is there a way to retrieve the number of notes on a tumblr post, without an API key?

Comment: What do you mean "retrieve"? Do you mean embed on your posts or manipulate with some type of script? Please provide your end objective as well

Comment: @ollie have you found the way to display without api key. i am looking for same things

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free API key in the documentation. I guess you dont want to register or you want use the Javascript API, which exposes you API key to the public:

https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts